# How to call a custom JS function in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In a client_server folder I've created a file called global_functions and defined

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    window.lg = function(text, pars){ // same problem with va lg = ...
        console.log(text);
    };

});
```

However when in server/server.js I write

```
lg("test server");
```

the application crashes

> ReferenceError: lg is not defined

Comment: Window isn't part of server, global is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply create a global variable by defining without `var` keyword. try this.

```
lg = function(text, pars){ // same problem with va lg = ...
 console.log(text);
};
```

and keep in mind that `window` object isn't available in meteor server side.

Comment: thank you. If I run lg("text") on server/server.js no problem at all. but on client_side (client/lib/events.js) I get "lg is not defined". any clue?

Comment: @dragonmnl remove your `Meteor.startup` wrapper. I think you don't need that.

Comment: I just tried to run the lg() client side on-click. it works. but if I just write lg () at the beginning of helpers.js file it doens't (like it wasn't yet loaded)

Comment: put your `global_functions` file  in `/lib` directory.

Comment: more about structuring your meteor app http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp